# Saving exceptions in database in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, exception

I have a Spring Boot application and database is MongoDB. I want to save all exceptions in MongoDB. I have following implementation for this:

**SaveException.class:**

```java
@Transactional
@Service
class SaveException{

    @Autowired
    SaveExceptionRepository SaveExceptionRepository;

    void save(Exception e) {
        SaveExceptionRepository.save(e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

I am calling this service from my `GlobalExceptionHandler.class`:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    
    @AutoWired
    SaveException saveException;
    
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(DuplicateKeyException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ApiErrorResponseMessage duplicateKeyException(DuplicateKeyException 
        duplicateKeyException) {
        log.info(duplicateKeyException.toString());
        saveException.save(duplicateKeyException);  //calling service here 
        // further exception handle code //
    }
}
```

But **saveError** is not able to be initialized and this implementation is giving me null pointer exception. Is there any work around for this implementation or if there is any other better way of implementation for storing exceptions to database.

Comment: Please put error stacktrace

Comment: make sure you add following dependency in pom.xml:         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>